# Why was my code highlighting edit rejected?

Tags: support, edits, code-formatting

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28695404) to a question's code block, from:

````
```import requests
...
````

to:

````
```python
import requests
...
````

This was a simple case of an asker writing unintended Markdown, and the edit fixed that. The edit was rejected, because:

> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.

I'm wondering if this edit is valid, and if not, why not? I'll note as well that the UI for reviewers is confusing. Even though only that small change was suggested, the side-by-side diff looks like this:

[image: diff between existing and edited code]

Comment: And why did you think " Now i got this It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. lmao" is worth keeping? I would have rejected your edit as well. You missed crucial issues in that post. If someone wonders, the edit is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28695404

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When making an edit you should address *all* the problems, the fact that there was a missing linebreak after the code fence (```) was started was just one of them.

The title could have done with an edit to remove the 3rd party site. Also the noise at the end needed removing:

> Now i got this
>
> **It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.** lmao

Finally, the error from the OP should probably have been put in a quote block, not code mark down.

TL;DR: Fix *all* the problems, not just 1 of them, in an edit suggestion.

Comment: Thanks; I was (incorrectly) under the impression that edits could be piecemeal, and that edits are valid so long as they improve the post in some way, not all the way.

Comment: When you can edit posts without review, then some people do it by piecemeal, @TJMazeika , (I personally hate it when people do this, as it keeps refreshing the question), but before then you *need* to ensure you address **all** the problems, or at least the vast majority of them. Though, like I imply, even once you have enough reputation, please don't do multiple piecemeal edits; make attempts to fully address all the problems in your edit.

Comment: @TJMazeika that is a view *some* reviewers hold, but it goes against editing guidelines. The problem with too minor suggested edits is that the review queue is hard-capped to 500 items at a time, and there is not enough reviewers to go through them precisely because they (including myself) burn out massively from slogging through incomplete or sometimes utterly pointless (which/that "fixes", for example) and even harmful edits. So, despite good intentions, I'd avoid submitting one unless you clean up the rest - as an added bonus, you will have a much higher chance of approval that way.